# Should I return an object wrapped by an article tag?

Tags: html, html5

Not sure if this is the right board for this topic but since it will affect my SEO i guess it's not that wrong to ask about this in here.

I just took on a website that lists some stores around your location.
You can enter some conditions and it will return a list of nearby stores.

I noticed that the List of stores will be returned as a `<section>` and each store is represented by an `<article>`.

```
<section class="stores">
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1>
                        <a href="http://foo.com/store1">       Ice Cream Store 1</a>                    </h1>
                </header>
                <div class="objekt_image">
                    <div class="image_wrapper">
                                                foo
                                            </div>
                </div>
                <div class="about">
                    foo     </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </article>

                        <article>
                <header>
                    <h1>
                        <a href="http://foo.com/store2">       Ice Cream Store 2</a>                    </h1>
                </header>
                <div class="objekt_image">
                    <div class="image_wrapper">
                                                foo2
                                            </div>
                </div>
                <div class="about">
                    foo     </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </article>

            ....
```

Is this good code style? I thought `<article>` should be represent ...well...articles about some topic like news or articles about a specific topic. Instead these articles are some stores which will change every few weeks. Whats the best way to represent a list like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element):

> The article element represents a complete, or self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

- Complete and self-contained? Yes - it has information about foostore which doesn't require the rest of the document to make sense.
- Composition? A work of music, literature, or art? Not really. It would work better if it included a review.
- One of the below:

  - A post? No.
  - An article? No.
  - Blog entry? No.
  - User-submitted content? Is it?
  - Interactive? No.

So probably not, as long as it isn't user-generated reviews.

Comment: thats what I thought, thanks for your review. So should I just use some <div> tags or is there a better way to represent a foostore

Comment: It looks like `<div>` is the best way. There are no elements specifically made for foostores...

Comment: Well, who knows what the next html specification update will bring us. So far I'll change it to <div> thanks mate.